# How can you find available WiFi devices?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I want to write an app that searches the available WiFi devices and connect.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this in android?
Thank you for your help

Comment: do you meen an app the connects to a wifi network? please be more specific.

Comment: You might look at [this solution](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/get-wifi-ip-of-android-device-using.html), but I am not sure about it as it is just a blog.

Comment: I mean connect a wireless sensor device and smarthphone

Answer (score 2):

use the following code to get available Wifi networks

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test_allActivity extends Activity {
 TextView mainText;
 WifiManager mainWifi;
 WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
 List<ScanResult> wifiList;
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
 mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
 registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
 WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
 mainWifi.startScan();
 mainText.setText("\nStarting Scan...\n");
 }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
  mainWifi.startScan();
  mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
  return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

protected void onPause() {
  unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
  super.onPause();
}

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
 sb = new StringBuilder();
 wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
 for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
  sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
  sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
  sb.append("\n");
  }
 mainText.setText(sb);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I mean connect a wireless sensor device and smarthphone.

Comment: you should clear about  your question

Comment: our sensor node send the data via wifi. Therefore, I must connect android smarthphone and sensor node.